# Where is perplexity calculated in the Huggingface gpt2 language model code?

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, google-publisher-tag, perplexity

I see some github comments saying the output of the model() call's loss is in the form of perplexity:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/473

But when I look at the relevant code...
https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/modeling_openai.html#OpenAIGPTLMHeadModel.forward

```
    if labels is not None:
        # Shift so that tokens < n predict n
        shift_logits = lm_logits[..., :-1, :].contiguous()
        shift_labels = labels[..., 1:].contiguous()
        # Flatten the tokens
        loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
        loss = loss_fct(shift_logits.view(-1, shift_logits.size(-1)), shift_labels.view(-1))
        outputs = (loss,) + outputs

    return outputs  # (loss), lm_logits, (all hidden states), (all attentions)
```

I see cross entropy being calculated, but no transformation into perplexity. Where does the loss finally get transformed? Or is there a transformation already there that I'm not understanding?

Comment: Could [this](https://jiangnanhugo.github.io/2016/perplexity-vs-cross-entropy/) be the answer to your question? I don't fully understand the article (which is why I'm only posting it as a comment), but it seems that there is an inherent relation between perplexity and CE loss...

Comment: There is a relationship, in that you need to calculate CE to get perplexity. I guess I am just confused as to where they are doing the 2^(CE Loss) in the code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah ok, I found the answer. The code is actually returning cross entropy. In the github comment where they say it is perplexity...they are saying that because the OP does

```
return math.exp(loss)
```

which transforms entropy to perplexity :)

Comment: Did you conclude that based on the definitions of cross entropy and perplexity? I have a rough idea what both are but I don't know that much details to make the same conclusion. If you have any recommendations/sources I'd be grateful.

Comment: Yup, but looking at the equations it is pretty straightforward to step through the code and see what is happening. Thankfully this is open source!

Answer (score 0):

No latex no problem. By definition the perplexity (triple P) is:

PP(p) = e^(H(p))

Where H stands for chaos (Ancient Greek: χάος) or entropy. In general case we have the cross entropy:

PP(p) = e^(H(p,q))

e is the natural base of the logarithm which is how PyTorch prefers to compute the entropy and cross entropy.